# Is there a German analog for the English expression, "It's not rocket science"?

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

I never heard *Raketenwissenschaft* in this context in Germany. Is this a case of anglicism, or are there better suited German synonyms for this expression?

Comment: IMHO *Raketenwissenschaft* isn't used at all in German. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luft-_und_Raumfahrttechnik

Comment: just heard that a current variation is "It's not rocket surgery" from ricon cf. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37026/which-kind-of-problems-are-described-as-thats-no-rocket-science

Comment: What do [rocket scientists say](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/03/7994007.aspx) when [something isn't hard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/16/9964049.aspx)? ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd probably say

> Das ist doch keine Wissenschaft.

or

> Das ist doch kein Hexenwerk.

LEO's forums contain a few more suggestions (e.g. [here](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=199938&idForum=2&lp=ende&lang=de)).

I wouldn't use *Raketenwissenschaft* or *rocket science* in German except when talking informally to peers of whom I know that they know English well enough.

Comment: Hexenwerk is what I'd use as well.

Comment: Definitely 'Hexenwerk'. The 'Wissenschaft' one doesn't feel strong enough to be a real synonym for me.

Comment: First: "Das ist doch keine Wissenschaft" is nowhere near to the vibrations in "no rocket science". "Hexenwerk" is good, but sounds to me very old fashioned and regional - most Germans would go for "Das ist keine Hexerei".

Answer (score 11):

I would go with

> Das ist nicht so kompliziert.

or

> Man braucht dafür nicht studiert zu haben.

or

> Das ist keine Hexerei.

I've never heard a literal translation of the English idiom.

Answer (score 2):

I commonly translate that with:

> Das ist keine Kernphysik.

or

> Dafür braucht man nicht Quantenmechanik studiert zu haben.

Comment: Agree. You also hear "Er ist nicht gerade ein Kernphysiker", meaning that somone isn't too smart. Admittedly, that's kind of mean.

Answer (score 2):

In context of scientific problems, I would say:

> Das ist kein offenes Forschungsproblem.

In other contexts I would say:

> Das ist machbar.

Or even

> Das ist kinderleicht.

BTW: I asked for the usage of "That's no rocket science" on [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37026/which-kind-of-problems-are-described-as-thats-no-rocket-science)

Comment: Good idea! We should focus a bit more on cross-side/language questions to attract some traffic or germans unaware of GL&U from there.

Comment: "Das ist kein offenes Forschungsproblem" will probably result in a confused stare, followed by laughter after a second or two if they're smart

Answer (score 2):

> Nowadays it is common to say
>
> Das ist keine Raketenwissenschaft.

I think it's true, but it has entered German language via English.

The military connotation of "rocket" is a bit more present in German. In English you have "missile" for the weapon, and in German "Mondrakete" for the space-ship (at least in the good old times).

"Raketenangriff" is a common term in todays news, and google translates it as "missile attack". This is pseudo-military in both languages, because it goes from near range to intercontinental.

Now a **bazooka** is a **rocket launcher**, it is true. I just found out that the (old) *Rak-Rohr* I used in the Swiss army was under a Belgian license for a **RL-83 Blindicide**

> **missile**, also known as a **guided missile**, is a guided airborne ranged
>   weapon capable of self-propelled flight usually by **a jet engine or
>   rocket motor**.

So I sometimes spoke of "Rakete" when I meant the ammunition - in a "Rak-Team" one carried (and then fired) the "tube", the other carried (and then loaded) two *missiles*. This again was confusing to some. But with that tube strapped around my neck, officially called "Rak Rohr", I had a good argument, and there was no better word.

I must add we fired only either small practice calibre or the real size, but without explosive in the tip (just red chalk). It also did not feel like a rocket, it went off with one big explosion. It was not guided.

The new model was tubeless, and suddenly was called "**Panzerfaust**". I remember that I almost refused to learn a new weapon with such a name. I did not mind using the same kind weapon as the Germans 60 years before, but not if it is called the same - *tank fist* instead of *rocket tube*, how *wagnerian*. Even the Belgian "blindicide" sounds better. Almost.

---

> Das ist keine Hexerei.

This is idiomatic, but it has a slightly different meaning. And also "Hexen" is a little bit *vorbelastet*.

---

If a German politician would want to argue in favor of his (complicated) plan, he could say:

> Dazu braucht es **keine höhere Mathematik**.

Meaning: yes, we have to use our brains, but everybody will be able to understand the solution.

It can also be used aginst somebody who is neglecting even simple math (the macht-nach-Adam-Riese kind of math).

This way you have

science (or Mathematik): yes

rockets (or "höhere"): no

Answer (score 0):

funny thing.  the rocket science nation doesn't use this expression. Germans use an expression from medival age:   Das ist kein Hexenwerk ----

word by word:  that's not a witch's work

annotation: "Werner von Braun" deliverd the work to the USA for building rockets to fly to the moon  (before he worked for Hitler building rockets to shoot England down)

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays it is common to say

> Das ist keine Raketenwissenschaft.