# Raketenwissenschaft

Tags: word-usage

Der Ausdruck "Das ist keine Raketenwissenschaft" ist ein Amerikanismus. Das englische Original "[It's not rocket science](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/it-s-not-rocket-science)" entstand vermutlich zu Beginn des US-amerikanischen Weltraumprogramms in den 1950-er oder 1960-er Jahren.

Von deutschen Sprechern und Autoren habe ich das englische Wort seit geraumer Zeit in Form von "das ist keine Rocket Science" vernommen. Es scheint, dass hier langsam ein Verdrängungsprozess stattfindet - zuungunsten von  "das ist keine Zauberei" oder "das ist kein Hexenwerk". Den schönen (rein deutschen) Ausdruck

> Das ist keine Raketenwissenschaft

habe ich erstmalig in Zusammenhang mit dem aktuellen [Wirecard-Skandal](https://www.zeit.de/news/2020-11/26/kpmg-sonderpruefer-wirecard-hat-uns-steine-in-den-weg-gelegt)  wahrgenommen. Die Wirtschaftsprüfungsgesellschaft KPMG deckte in einer Sonderprüfung auf, "dass es keine Nachweise zur Existenz von angeblichen Kundenbeziehungen und daraus erzielten Umsätzen des aufstrebenden Tech-Konzerns gab." Alexander Geschonneck von KPMG sagte, dass er dafür keine speziellen Methoden anwenden musste: "Es ist keine Raketenwissenschaft, was wir da gemacht haben".

Meine Frage: Wann und wo wurde das deutsche Wort *Raketenwissenschaft* erstmalig in dieser Bedeutung verwendet?

**Ergänzung**

Das Wort *Raketenwissenschaft* ist definitiv eine wörtliche Übersetzung aus dem Englischen, wirkt aber m.E. im Deutschen (noch?) wie ein Fremdkörper, zumal das englische "science" nicht mit dem deutschen "Wissenschaft" gleichgesetzt werden sollte. Die Vermutung liegt daher nahe, dass das Wort durch unüberlegte Übersetzungen von englischen Texten ins Deutsche gelangte.

Eine weitere Quelle sind vermutlich international operierende Unternehmen wie KPMG, in denen häufig auf Englisch kommuniziert wird. Da entsteht aus dem rein englischen "It's not rocket science" leicht der Mix "Das ist keine Rocket Science" und schließlich das rein deutsche "Das ist keine Raketenwissenschaft" - und das wird dann irgendwann nach außen getragen.

Comment: Wiktionary lists *Raumfahrttechnik* as a translation for the idiomatic meaning of "rocket science", but I gather it exclusively has the literal meaning, something like "space technology". Overall it's the more common word though. I'll go ahead and correct the entry unless someone claims to have seen it used in the idiomatic sense. A related idiom in English is "brain surgery", but I have no idea if there's a German equivalent.

Comment: Essentially same [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2061/1696) in English.

Comment: @guidot Danke für den Hinweis, die verlinkte Frage ist mir entgangen. Interessant ist, dass in dieser Frage aus dem Jahr 2011 noch gesagt wird "I never heard Raketenwissenschaft in this context in Germany".

Comment: Ein Treffer von [1852](https://books.google.de/books?id=_omRjDfBBQkC&q=Raketen-Wissenschaft#v=snippet&q=Raketen-Wissenschaft&f=false).

Comment: @RDBury I have never heard the phrase "Das ist keine Gehirnchirurgie" in German, but in my opinion it sounds much better than the Raketenwissenschaft-phrase. "Gehirnchirurgie" is a well-established German word, but "Raketenwissenschaft" cannot obscure its English origin. So let this new genie out of the bottle ...

Comment: @DavidVogt Sehr interessant, dass so früh schon Raketen-**Wissenschaft** verwendet wurde. Es war mir auch nicht bewusst, dass Raketen schon sehr lange militärisch eingesetzt wurden.  Vgl. [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rakete). Nach heutigem Usus klingt allerdings auch das im Text von 1852 benutzte Wort *Artillerie-Wissenschaft* merkwürdig.

Comment: *Simpsons already did it* - da meinte Mr. Burns einst: *It's brain surgery, not rocket science.*

Comment: @Paul Frost -- "Rocket science" isn't well-established in English either except for that one phrase. It's redolent of chain-smoking men sporting slide rules and crew cuts. Any actual "aerospace engineer" would laugh at being called a "rocket scientist". So the fact that "Raketenwissenschaft" sounds odd in German actually works in it's favor imo.

Comment: Mir fallen im Deutschen folgende Varianten ein: "Das ist keine Hexerei", "... kein Zauberwerk" oder "... keine Zauberei"

Comment: @RDBury Your comment  suggests that "It's not rocket science" sounds weird also in English. But "brain surgery" seems to be well-established in English (see  Bernhard Döbler's comment) as well as in German, and this supports my suggestion to introduce "Das ist keine Gehirnchirurgie" in German.;-)

Comment: @Paul Frost -- Yes, the English is not consistent. Idioms tend to catch obsolete phrases like flies in amber, but sometimes the phrase doesn't become obsolete. Btw, Google translate turns "rocket science" into *Hexenwerk* -- sounds like it's from Grimms' Fairy Tales.

Comment: @RDBury "Hexenwerk" (= "sorcery") is a strange word in contemporary German. It has a medevial origin - but I think everybody understands it. I mentioned it in my question. Anyway, " Raketenwissenschaft" sounds *really weird*.

Comment: Wie soll man die Frage nach erstmaliger Verwendung beantworten können? Dazu müsste man alle Bücher, Zeitungen, Flugblätter und Werbeschriften kennen, alle (privaten) Briefe und Postkarten, alle Radio- und Fernsehsendungen sowie alle Telefonate abgehört haben wie auch alle Gespräche überhaupt und überall. VTC

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using *Hexenwerk*, *Hexerei* or *Geheimwissenschaft* in this context. After all, we know the famous Arthur C. Clarke quote: 'Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **Raketenwissenschaft oder keine Raketenwissenschaft?**

Zunächst sei bemerkt, dass das Wort *Raketenwissenschaft* bereits sicher nach dem Ende des zweiten Weltkriegs auftrat. Der erste Peak bei Google NGram liegt um 1948/49. Anfang des 21. Jahrhunderts scheint er dann vemehrt wieder aufzutreten.

[image]

*Keine Raketenwissenschaft* wiederum taucht bei Google NGram erst ab dem 21. Jahrhundert auf:

[image]

Dabei scheinen beide Kurven etwa ab 2012 deckungsgleich zu sein. Nach Variationen zu suchen, wie z.B. *dabei handelt es sich nicht um Raketenwissenschaft*, gestaltet sich als schwieriger, oder ich weiß nicht, wie das sinnvoll geht.

## **Schriftliche Belege**

Zumindest in Stichproben bis zum Jahre 1993 scheint das Wort Raketenwissenschaft noch im technischen Sinne gebraucht zu werden, so findet sich in der [Chronik der Technik (1998)](https://books.google.de/books?id=JhBSAQAAIAAJ&q=%22raketenwissenschaft%22&dq=%22raketenwissenschaft%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJns6RyMftAhVx5-AKHSQHCEEQ6AEwCHoECAcQAg)

> Der russische Mathematiklehrer Konstantin E. Ziolkowski stellt eine Theorie des Raketenantriebs auf und begründet damit die Raketenwissenschaft.

Einen der ersten schriftlichen Belege finde ich in [Die 11 Geheimnisse des ALDI-Erfolgs (2003)](https://books.google.de/books?id=fVhwAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&dq=%22Raketenwissenschaft%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9qa2AycftAhWCjqQKHYJDADYQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Raketenwissenschaft%22&f=false)

> Die Komplexität der Unternehmensführung wird überschätzt. Das ist keine Raketenwissenschaft. (Jack Welch)

Dies scheint zweifelsfrei einfach eine wörtliche Übersetzung eines Zitats des amerikanischen Managers Jack Welch zu sein, welches die ursprüngliche Annahme des OP stützt, dass es ein Amerikanismus ist.

Das früheste was ich finden konnte, findet sich in der [3. Ausgabe des Spiegel Reporter (2001)](https://books.google.de/books?id=Rj4XAQAAMAAJ&q=%22Raketenwissenschaft%22&dq=%22Raketenwissenschaft%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9qa2AycftAhWCjqQKHYJDADYQ6AEwBnoECAkQAg), dort heißt es:

> "Scheidungsrecht ist nicht gerade Raketenwissenschaft", sagt er.

## **Fazit**

Vergleicht man meine obigen Funde in Büchern/Magazinen mit den obigen Graphen, so dürfte das Wort Raketenwissenschaft im *it's not rocket science* - Sinne etwa um die Jahrtausendwende erstmalig aufgetreten zu sein. Definitiv belegbar spätestens 2001, womöglich bereits um 1998 (Peak in ngram, aber leider kein korrespondierendes Schriftstück). Ausschließen, dass es bereits deutlich früher auftrat, lässt es sich natürlich nicht, scheint aber unwahrscheinlich zu sein.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort (+1). Es scheint also wirklich so zu sein, dass die Quelle in  (m.E. schlechten) Übersetzungen liegt. Das dürfte auch bei "Spiegel Reporter" so sein - ich vermute, dass das zugrundeliegende Interview auf Englisch geführt wurde.

Answer (score 1):

Ja. Ganz sicher eine Amerikanismus. Ich habe das noch nie in meinem Leben so auf Deutsch gehört. Und ich bin 1997 aus Deutschland nach Amerika umgezogen. (Damals haben wir noch mit D-Mark bezahlt.) Ich könnte mir gut vorstellen, dass das von ihnen genannte Zitat der erste Beleg ist. Es klingt nicht gut.

Was würden wir an solcher Stelle idiomatisch und natürlich sagen? "Das ist keine Kunst" ist eine alte Redewendung. Ich habe auch schon "Das ist keine höhere Mathematik" gehört. "Raketenwissenschaft" ist nicht einmal an und für sich ein Begriff, den es in Deutschland geben würde, auch wenn Deutschland das Erfinderland der Rakete ist (Wernher von Braun und so). Die Studenten studieren "Luft und Raumfahrttechnik" und nicht "Raumfahrtwissenschaft".

Comment: -1. "Ich könnte mir gut vorstellen, dass das von ihnen genannte Zitat der erste Beleg ist.", ist das einzige, was irgendwie auf die Frage eingeht und ist auch nur eine Vermutung.

Comment: 'Die Studenten studieren "Luft und Raumfahrttechnik" und nicht "Raumfahrtwissenschaft".' - während "Luft- und Raumfahrttechnik" wohl in der Tat der *verbreitetere Begriff ist, scheint "Raumfahrtwissenschaft" keineswegs komplett unbekannt zu sein. So gibt [ein entsprechendes Institut der TU Dresden an, "ein breites Fächerspektrum im Bereich der Luft- und Raumfahrtwissenschaft" zu bieten](https://tu-dresden.de/ing/maschinenwesen/ilr/studium) und auch die [DGLR kennt einen Bereich namens "Raumfahrtwissenschaft und -anwendung"](https://r2.dglr.de/).